# Object that is not yet saved term

Tags: nhibernate, naming, naming-conventions

Is there a term/suitable name for an object that will be saved in database but it **is not yet**?

---

Transient seems suitable name but I found in Tobin Harris`ons article:

> ...These tend to be the ones I want NHibernate to persist, but there are
>   also some classes in there that are not persisted (aka transient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider this to be `Transient`

Comment: So object that will never be saved and object that is not yet saved are both Transient?